# IE 11 is Unresponsive when loading thousand of data to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11

Making a dashboard for a company but users are using internet explorer 11 as browser. The problem is when IE is trying to fill a Table with thousands of data from a database, IE becomes unresponsive and just hangs for a few seconds until all the data is loaded. I even added a loading div and it works fine for chrome, but when IE becomes unresponsive the loading div is just frozen.

Is there a way to keep IE responsive while loading the Data?
Thanks!

Comment: How are you loading the data? Do you mean you're dynamically adding thousands of rows to a `<table>` element? How many seconds is "a few"?

Comment: don't load thousands of data at one time,

use pagination or server side pagination,

get less data in front end

Comment: can you share your code please? how are you loading the data? is it using REST API/ JSON?

Comment: It also makes a big difference in how you build the table when adding it via JavaScript. inserting dom nodes 1 by 1 is just very slow in any browser. But even so, I don't see any good reason to load thousands of lines in 1 go.

Comment: data is being loaded into a table with DataTable plugin with pagination, 
It takes about 8seconds to load,

Comment: How much data it actually loads? A Mega, two, more? Avoid heavily CCS-styled rows and cells. Use [HTMLTable API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement), insert new rows to the tbody element instead of the table element. Also include the table and the tbody in the hardcoded HTML, for some reason row creation is much slower when using dynamically created tables.

Answer (score 2):

IE's rendering engine is orders of magnitude slower than other browsers, and there's not much you can do about it. You need to change how you present or load your data.

The best course of action is to introduce good old-fashioned pagination to your table. You can either do this server-side or client-side.

If you cannot change the server code, then you are stuck with the client-side solution. Instead of rendering the entire table all at once, you slice the array of data records such that only a portion is rendered. You also need to keep a reference to what portion is currently loaded so you can provide interfaces for loading next and/or previous page.

If you are using a plugin to render the table and the plugin does not support pagination, you cannot use that plugin for your project.